# Mocking a simple function in react.js, jest, enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, tdd, enzyme

I am new to testing in react and am building a simple todo application. I am struggling to mock the delete function in the lists component.

My test looks like this at the moment

```
  it('deletes an item from the list', () => {
    const deleteItem = jest.fn();
    const items = [{body: "New note", id: "12345"}]
    const textEl = wrapper.find("#text-output p")
    wrapper = shallow(<ListItems list={items} deleteItem={deleteItem}/>)
    wrapper.find('#delete').simulate('click')
    expect(textEl.text()).toContain("//Should be empty")
  })
```

currently the when I run the tests the error reads..

```
Expected substring: "//Should be empty"
Received string:    "New note X"
```

The application works fine, but I am not mocking the delete function correctly in my test as a "New Note" is still being passed through. What am I doing wrong?

just in case it helps, here is the file I am testing..

```
function ListItems(props) {
   const list = props.list
    const displayItems = list.map((item, index) => 
    {
      return <div id='text-output' key={index}>
            <p>
              {item.body } 
              &nbsp;
              <button
              id="delete"
              onClick={ () => props.deleteItem(item.id)}>
                X
              </button>
            </p>
        </div>
    })
  return(
  <div>
    <h1>This is the list</h1>
    {displayItems}
  </div>
  )
}
```

any help would be great!

Comment: In your test since you mocked the `deleteItem` callback it doesn't *actually* delete an item from the `items` object passed to the `list` prop. You *can* however instead assert the `deleteItem` mock was called with the specified item id. TBH, that is what the test should be anyway since that component under test doesn't appear to have any logic *other than* rendering a list of items and attaching an `onClick` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test since you mocked the `deleteItem` callback it doesn't *actually* delete an item from the `items` object passed to the `list` prop. Also, `const textEl = wrapper.find("#text-output p")` *before* `wrapper = shallow(<ListItems list={items} deleteItem={deleteItem}/>)` probably also won't work as expected.

You *can* however instead assert the `deleteItem` mock was called with the specified item id. TBH, that is what the test should be anyway since that component under test doesn't appear to have any logic *other than* rendering a list of items and attaching an `onClick` callback.

[.toHaveBeenCalledWith](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-)

```
it('should invoke deleteItem callback on button click with item id', () => {
  const deleteItemMock = jest.fn();
  const items = [{body: "New note", id: "12345"}];

  wrapper = shallow(<ListItems list={items} deleteItem={deleteItemMock}/>);
  wrapper.find('#delete').simulate('click');

  expect(deleteItemMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("12345");
});
```